# Function of a function and checking if true in python

Tags: python

Alright so I have coded a program that checks prime numbers with two different methods. I also made a program that counts the number of prime numbers that the functions find under a given number. I also compare these later and find % difference. However, I am curious if there's a way for the prime counter code to take on the two different prime checkers as variables so I don't have to write two separate counters for each method. How could I make something like that?

The code is something like this

```
def primsqr(x):
    if x>1:
        for i in range(2, int(x ** 0.5) + 1):
            if x % i == 0:
                break
                return False
        else:
            return True
def primeferm(x):
    if x>1:
        if pow(2, (x-1), mod=x) == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def counter():
    primeamount = 0
    for i in range(3000001):
        if primsqr(i) == True:
            primeamount +=1
    return primeamount

#And then an identical one for the other prime checker and the comparison blablabla
#This is also pseudocode
```

Any chance I could just make a general function for counting prime amounts under a number instead of writing the last one two times? Maybe something that makes the prime checker as a parameter and makes a general function?

Comment: I advise you to read about decorators

Comment: Tangential comment: you can get the sum much more easily with `sum(function(i) for i in range(3000001))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the function that you want to use as parameter.

```py
def counter(prime_checker):
    primeamount = 0
    for i in range(3000001):
        if prime_checker(i) == True:
            primeamount +=1
    return primeamount

counter(primsqr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take a function as parameter.

```
def counter(function):
    primeamount = 0
    for i in range(3000001):
        if function(i) == True:
            primeamount +=1
    return primeamount

print(counter(primsqr))
print(counter(primeferm))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass functions as arguments

```
def counter(func):
    primeamount = 0
    for i in range(3000001):
        if func(i) == True:
            primeamount +=1
    return primeamount


counter(primsqr) #or counter(primeferm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions in python are objects just like primitive types (integers, strings, lists, etc.). Like users have said above you can pass functions as parameters in Python functions.

```
def counter(function):
    primeamount = 0
    for i in range(3000001):
        if function(i) == True:
            primeamount +=1
    return primeamount

print(counter(primsqr))
print(counter(primeferm))
```